# How to convert a complex JSON to CSV in Java

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, csv, jackson

I am having a `complex.json` file and I want it to convert into CSV file using Java Spring boot.

Below is my `complex.json` file:

```
{
  "requestId": "1P02XV425KCASEZGQLB8LPQMF4ZXCURRR01",
  "recyleBinRecords": [
    {
      "Record": {
        "ProductName": "Name1",
        "Id": "1P02XV425KCASEZGQLB8LPQMF4ZXCUBCTA01"
        "ProductArea": "Area1"
      },
      "dependecyMaterial": [
        {
          "Name": "D1",
          "id": "1P02XV425KCASEZGQLB8LPQMF4ZXCUBCTA01",
          "parentid": "1P02XV425KCASEZGQLB8LPQMF4ZXCUBCTA01",
          "value": "Value1"
        },
        {
          "Name": "d2",
          "id": "1P02XV425KCASEZGQLB8LPQMF4ZXCUBCTA01",
          "parentid": "1P02XV425KCASEZGQLB8LPQMF4ZXCUBCTA01",
          "value": "value2"
        }]},{
      "Record": {
        "ProductName": "Name2",
        "Id": "1P02XV425KCASEZGQLB8LPQMF4ZXCUBCTA01",
        "ProductArea": "Product2"
      },
      "dependecyMaterial": [
        {
          "Name": "D3",
          "id": "1P02XV425KCASEZGQLB8LPQMF4ZXCUBCTA01",
          "parentid": "P1",
          "value": "value1"
        },
        {
          "Name": "D4",
          "id": "1P02XV425KCASEZGQLB8LPQMF4ZXCUBCTA01",
          "parentid": "P2",
          "value": "value2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is code I tried but it's giving **no column exception**.

```
JsonNode jsonTree = new ObjectMapper().readTree(new File("src/main/resources/complex.json"));
Builder csvSchemaBuilder = CsvSchema.builder();
JsonNode firstObject = jsonTree.elements().next();
firstObject.fieldNames().forEachRemaining(fieldName -> {csvSchemaBuilder.addColumn(fieldName);} );
CsvSchema csvSchema = csvSchemaBuilder.build().withHeader();
```

```
CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
csvMapper.writerFor(JsonNode.class)
  .with(csvSchema)
  .writeValue(new File("src/main/resources/orderLines.csv"), jsonTree);Copy
```

Need a solution to convert my JSON to CSV in java.

Comment: Could you provide more error details (stack trace)?
Also, you need a `comma (,)` on the 7th line (after `"Id": "1P02XV425KCASEZGQLB8LPQMF4ZXCUBCTA01"`).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that are causing this. Main reason for the exception you are getting is that your csv schema does not have columns to map. Run a debugger and see what the line `JsonNode firstObject = jsonTree.elements().next();` returns and what fields are added to the schema when you run `firstObject.fieldNames().forEachRemaining(fieldName -> {csvSchemaBuilder.addColumn(fieldName);} );`

Having said that, the parsing may still not go through as  CSV generator does not support nested Objects. There are several ways to handle this. You can write a custom method to handle the structure and spit out flattened data or use a library to handle the transformation. One way that I have done it in the past is by using the JOLT library (json to json transform) to pre-process the JSON and create an interim document and parsing it. See details in this answer - [Return a JSON response as CSV file from spring-boot controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74712859/return-a-json-response-as-csv-file-from-spring-boot-controller/74713492#74713492)